Reading small files is too slow
I have 3 millions small jpeg images (256x256 resolution). When I read them using the PIL library in python (using PIL.Image.open method), the reading time is highly variable. It can take as low as 1ms and as high as 500ms, there is a huge variance in this reading time. The average reading time is 20ms.
After I read a set of files, if I reread them it's very fast for all files (1ms) probably because of caching of the filesystem.
How can I read these files with the best reading time corresponding to my HDD specs ?

You really haven't demonstrated that the problem is in the way the files are read, in fact you strongly imply that it's the fault of the OS.  If so there's likely nothing you can do.

I agree with @MarkRansom, if the caching alleviates the problem, then the problem is in the hardware and/or OS, and nothing you do in Python will fix that. On the other hand, you could instead ask how to store many small images so that reading is fast…

Having 3 million small jpeg files is not something normal and reading all of them will take at least few seconds whatever the target SSD. Each file needs several IO operations to be opened/read/closed. Typically, even with a good SSD reaching 300_000 IOPS (sustained stable bandwidth), I expect this to take at least 1 minute.

If you want to read many files quickly, then you need to pack them in big flat archive file. This is for example what all AAA video games does to read a lot of file rather quickly.

By the way, some SSDs can throttle or switch to low-power modes. This often explain instable read/write timing (especially write ones).

Why do you need 3 million images in RAM? What do you plan to do with them? If this is something you do often, put them on a RAMdisk and avoid all disk latencies.
